# Clonar elementos html

Tags: javascript

Como puedo ***clonar elementos de html*** y poder cambiarle sus propiedades independientemente?

Intenté con esto:

```js
function clonar(){
  var c = document.getElementById("about0");
  var clon = c.cloneNode(true);
  clon.style.width = "1000px";
  document.body.appendChild(clon);
}
```

```css
#about {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 175px;
  background-color:gray;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="about"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Con "independiente" me refiero a que a los elementos clonados les pueda cambiar sus propiedades, osea de todas las propiedades que heredó, si quiero cambiarle el color, etc.***

Comment: Se acepta jquery?

Comment: Quiero Javascript puro @Einer

Comment: aaawww :(. Por cierto. Cual es el error con tu implementacion?

Comment: Que no aparece el clon

Comment: ¿Será porque intentas clonar un elemento que no existe? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estas invocando la funcion `clonar()` y el id `about0` no existe, deberia ser `about`

```js
function clonar() {
  var c = document.getElementById("about");
  var clon = c.cloneNode("about");
  clon.style.width = "50px";
  clon.style.height = "50px";
  document.body.appendChild(clon);

 
}
clonar();
```

```css
#about {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 175px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="about"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si se está invocando la función, con el evento onclick dentro de este elemento.

Answer (score 4):

Segun la documentacion se puede utilizar [Node#cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

> El método Node.cloneNode () devuelve un duplicado del nodo en el que
>   se llamó este método.

Y claramente lo estas utilizando lo que entiendo que el error que tienes es que no estas llamando la funcion clonar y estas utilizando el id equivocado, en vez de `about0`, deberia de ser `about`.
Aqui tu ejemplo editado

```js
function clonar(){
  var c = document.getElementById("about");
  var clon = c.cloneNode(true);
  clon.style.width = "1000px";
  document.body.appendChild(clon);
  
}
```

```css
#about {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 175px;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="about" onclick="clonar()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```